# Can I combine a gRPC and webapi app into a .NET Core 3.0 in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, grpc

I am using dot net core 3.0.

I have gRPC app. I am able to communicate to it through gRPC protocol.

I thought my next step would be add some restful API support. I modified my startup class to add controllers, routing etc..... When I try navigating to the API using a browser, I get an error "ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE" no matter which protocol (http/https) and port I use.  gRPC should be using 5001 and webapi using 8001.

heres my startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<BootNodeService>();
            endpoints.MapControllers();

        });
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")] 
public class AdminController : ControllerBase 
{ 
    [HttpGet] public string Get() 
    { return "hello"; } 
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thnx

**EDIT**:  the entire project can be found at [this repo](https://github.com/matt-raffel-kiva/node).

**EDIT**: view of screen
[image]

Comment: do you have a github repo or something with full code (like your .csproj, and `BootNodeService` class)

Comment: @BurnsBA sure.  I added the link at the bottom the body of my question.

Comment: Are you sure your web port is on port 8001? It looks like your project is configured for 11837/44380 (http/https). I cloned your project and hit f5, browser auto loads `https://localhost:44380/admin` and it shows "hello from admin"

Comment: @BurnsBA ok.  thank you.  were you using macos by chance?

Comment: no macros. Visual Studio 2019, though it should build the same with any msbuild tools for dotnet core 3

Comment: @BurnsBA  Solved because you made me realize something.  I'll post a solution in a moment. I had to do some "trick" get gPRC to work on macos.  I applied that same trick to the port for webapi and it works now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution. I didn't mention I was running on MacOS and using Kestrel (and it appears the combination of MacOS AND Kestrel is the problem). I apologize for that missing information.

The solution is similar to what is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.0#unable-to-start-aspnet-core-grpc-app-on-macos). I had to add a call to `options.ListenLocalhost` for the webapi port.

here's the code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       IHostBuilder hostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args);
       IHost host = hostBuilder.Build();
       host.Run();
    }

    // Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
    // For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenLocalhost(5001, o => o.Protocols =
                        HttpProtocols.Http2);

                    // ADDED THIS LINE to fix the problem
                    options.ListenLocalhost(11837, o => o.Protocols =
                        HttpProtocols.Http1);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
    }
}
```

Thnx

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is configure Kestrel parameter on `appsettings.json`. It work with **.Net Core 3.1** too.

Edit `appsettings.json` and set Endpoints with WebApi and gRPC with your custom name. You don't need change the `Program.cs`.

```js
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "WebApi": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5001",
        "Protocols": "Http1"
      },
      "gRPC": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:11837",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```